# Inno Setup Call AfterInstall for each external File

Tags: inno-setup

I am really struggling with this one.  I have an entry in the files section of an Inno Setup (5.5.9) configuration file, that is something like the following:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure showMsgBoxOfFile;
begin
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant(CurrentFilename), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

```
[Files]
Source: {src}\Some\Path\myFile*Pattern.ext; DestDir: {app}; Flags: external; \
    AfterInstall: showMsgBoxOfFile;
```

When I run the installer generated by running the above script, I get a single message box with the `{app}` directory, even though four files are copied.  This seems to be in direct contradiction of the [Inno Setup documentation on BeforeInstall/AfterInstall](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall), which states:

> A BeforeInstall or AfterInstall function for a [Files] section entry using a wildcard is called once per file matching the wildcard. Use CurrentFileName to check for which file the function is called.

Further, another question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248324/inno-setup-afterinstall-function-called-for-each-file) is from a user who wanted to do the exact opposite (get only one notification when multiple files were changed).  The accepted answer to that question indicates that:

> there is no way to call [AfterInstall] once after all the files are installed

I noticed that if I remove the "external" flag from my file copy, I DO get one message box per file.  Is there a way to get a one notification per copied file when the "external" flag is specified?  Does anyone know if there is a plan to document this difference in the Inno Setup help files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for entries with the `external` flag, the `BeforeInstall` and `AnswerInstall` functions are called only once.

What you can do, is to copy the files programmatically. It would give you a full control over, what you do for each file.

See [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848)